# PHP 7.3 / Libzip Compile Errors (CWP)

Tags: php, libzip

I'm using Centos Web Panel.
[System details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fem8d.png)

Currently my system:

Apache/2.4.39, PHP 7.2.26, nginx-varnish-apache

-

### I need help about PHP rebuilding or updating.

PHP 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, with FPM, without FPM... it doesn't matter. Same errors.

```
2020-04-30 03:01:57 (5.60 MB/s) - 'libzip-1.5.1.tar.gz.1' saved [1189827/1189827]

tar (child): libzip-1.5.1: Cannot read: Is a directory
tar (child): At beginning of tape, quitting now
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
mkdir: cannot create directory 'build': File exists
-- Could NOT find NETTLE (missing: NETTLE_LIBRARY NETTLE_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find GnuTLS (missing: GNUTLS_LIBRARY GNUTLS_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /usr/local/src/libzip-1.5.1/build
[ 46%] Built target zip
[ 85%] Built target man
[ 85%] Linking C executable ziptool
../lib/libzip.so.5.0: undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_free'
../lib/libzip.so.5.0: undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_new'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/ziptool] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/ziptool.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:2346: undefined reference to `X509_get_version'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:2373: undefined reference to `X509_getm_notBefore'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:2374: undefined reference to `X509_getm_notAfter'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:2376: undefined reference to `X509_getm_notBefore'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:2377: undefined reference to `X509_getm_notAfter'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_GENERAL_NAME_pop_free':
/usr/include/openssl/x509v3.h:166: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_pop_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_GENERAL_NAME_num':
/usr/include/openssl/x509v3.h:166: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_GENERAL_NAME_value':
/usr/include/openssl/x509v3.h:166: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_value'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `openssl_x509v3_subjectAltName':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:2276: undefined reference to `ASN1_STRING_get0_data'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_new_null':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_new_null'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_free':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_INFO_free':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:254: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_INFO_shift':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:254: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_shift'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_push':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_push'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_INFO_num':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:254: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_num':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_free':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_free'
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_free'
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_pop_free':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_pop_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_new_null':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_new_null'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_push':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_push'
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_push'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_num':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_pop':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_pop'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_free':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_csr_get_subject':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3628: undefined reference to `X509_REQ_get_subject_name'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_pkey_get_details':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4825: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_DH'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4832: undefined reference to `DH_get0_pqg'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4833: undefined reference to `DH_get0_key'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4847: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_EC_KEY'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4856: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_EC_KEY'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4803: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_DSA'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4810: undefined reference to `DSA_get0_pqg'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4811: undefined reference to `DSA_get0_key'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4774: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4781: undefined reference to `RSA_get0_key'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4782: undefined reference to `RSA_get0_factors'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4783: undefined reference to `RSA_get0_crt_params'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4892: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_EC_KEY'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_dh_compute_key':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4935: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_DH'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_value':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_value'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_num':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_free':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_pop_free':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_pop_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_new_null':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_new_null'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_push':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_push'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_pop_free':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_pop_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_push':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_push'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_num':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_value':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_value'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_CRL_num':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:228: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_CRL_value':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:228: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_value'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_pop_free':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_pop_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_private_encrypt':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:5683: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_private_decrypt':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:5745: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_public_encrypt':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:5813: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_public_decrypt':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:5876: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_sign':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:5984: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_new'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:5999: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_verify':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:6051: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_new'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:6058: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_seal':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:6145: undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_reset'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_digest':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:6376: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_new'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:6399: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_encrypt':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:6698: undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_reset'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_decrypt':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:6785: undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_reset'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_CONF_VALUE_num':
/usr/include/openssl/conf.h:30: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_CONF_VALUE_value':
/usr/include/openssl/conf.h:30: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_value'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_csr_sign':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3459: undefined reference to `X509_REQ_get_subject_name'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3468: undefined reference to `X509_getm_notBefore'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3469: undefined reference to `X509_getm_notAfter'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `php_openssl_make_REQ':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3096: undefined reference to `X509_REQ_get_subject_name'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_CONF_VALUE_num':
/usr/include/openssl/conf.h:30: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_CONF_VALUE_value':
/usr/include/openssl/conf.h:30: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_value'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_CONF_VALUE_num':
/usr/include/openssl/conf.h:30: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
/usr/include/openssl/conf.h:30: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_CONF_VALUE_value':
/usr/include/openssl/conf.h:30: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_value'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `php_openssl_pkey_init_and_assign_rsa':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4156: undefined reference to `RSA_set0_key'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4162: undefined reference to `RSA_set0_factors'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `php_openssl_pkey_init_dsa':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4190: undefined reference to `DSA_set0_pqg'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4197: undefined reference to `DSA_set0_key'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `php_openssl_pkey_init_dh':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4267: undefined reference to `DH_set0_pqg'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `php_openssl_dh_pub_from_priv':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4244: undefined reference to `BN_with_flags'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `php_openssl_pkey_init_dh':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4281: undefined reference to `DH_set0_key'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `php_openssl_pkey_init_dsa':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4209: undefined reference to `DSA_get0_key'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4210: undefined reference to `BN_is_zero'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `php_openssl_pkey_init_and_assign_rsa':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4169: undefined reference to `RSA_set0_crt_params'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `php_openssl_pkey_init_dh':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4274: undefined reference to `DH_set0_key'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_pkey_export_to_file':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4564: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_EC_KEY'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_pkey_export':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4641: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_EC_KEY'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_free':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `php_openssl_create_sni_server_ctx':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1377: undefined reference to `TLS_server_method'
ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `sk_X509_num':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `sk_X509_value':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_value'
ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `sk_X509_num':
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:99: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `php_openssl_setup_crypto':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1621: undefined reference to `TLS_server_method'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1678: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_security_level'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1621: undefined reference to `TLS_client_method'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1719: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_options'
ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `php_openssl_set_server_specific_opts':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1308: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_get_options'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1335: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_options'
ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `sk_GENERAL_NAME_num':
/usr/include/openssl/x509v3.h:166: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `sk_GENERAL_NAME_value':
/usr/include/openssl/x509v3.h:166: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_value'
ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `sk_GENERAL_NAME_pop_free':
/usr/include/openssl/x509v3.h:166: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_pop_free'
/usr/include/openssl/x509v3.h:166: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_pop_free'
/usr/include/openssl/x509v3.h:166: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_pop_free'
ext/ftp/.libs/php_ftp.o: In function `zm_startup_ftp':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/ftp/php_ftp.c:321: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/ftp/php_ftp.c:322: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_crypto'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/ftp/php_ftp.c:323: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_crypto'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/ftp/php_ftp.c:324: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_crypto'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/ftp/php_ftp.c:326: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
ext/ftp/.libs/ftp.o: In function `ftp_login':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/ftp/ftp.c:275: undefined reference to `TLS_client_method'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/ftp/ftp.c:284: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_options'
ext/phar/.libs/util.o: In function `phar_verify_signature':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/phar/util.c:1561: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_new'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/phar/util.c:1593: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_free'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/phar/util.c:1584: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_free'
ext/phar/.libs/util.o: In function `phar_create_signature':
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/phar/util.c:1858: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_new'
/usr/local/src/php-build/php-7.3.17/ext/phar/util.c:1890: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
mkdir: cannot create directory '/opt/alt/php-fpm73/usr/var/sockets/': No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory '/opt/alt/php-fpm73/usr/etc/php-fpm.d/': No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory '/opt/alt/php-fpm73/usr/etc/php-fpm.d/users/': No such file or directory
/usr/local/src/php-fpm-7.3.sh: line 98: /opt/alt/php-fpm73/usr/etc/php-fpm.d/users.conf: No such file or directory
/usr/local/src/php-fpm-7.3.sh: line 99: /opt/alt/php-fpm73/usr/etc/php-fpm.conf: No such file or directory
/usr/local/src/php-fpm-7.3.sh: line 101: /opt/alt/php-fpm73/usr/etc/php-fpm.d/cwpsvc.conf: No such file or directory
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
Skipping as php build failed
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
Skipping as php build failed
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
Skipping as php build failed
exe:/opt/alt/php-fpm73/usr/sbin/php-fpm
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart httpd.service

Build Completed
###################

Error:Can't add notification!
```

I tried installing PHP manually but libzip gives error.

```
[ 82%] Preparing zip_source_write.3
[ 82%] Preparing zip_source_zip.3
[ 83%] Preparing zip_stat.3
[ 83%] Preparing zip_stat_init.3
[ 83%] Preparing zip_unchange.3
[ 83%] Preparing zip_unchange_all.3
[ 85%] Preparing zip_unchange_archive.3
[ 85%] Preparing zipcmp.1
[ 85%] Preparing zipmerge.1
[ 85%] Preparing ziptool.1
[ 85%] Built target man
Scanning dependencies of target ziptool
[ 87%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/ziptool.dir/ziptool.c.o
[ 87%] Linking C executable ziptool
../lib/libzip.so.5.0: undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_free'
../lib/libzip.so.5.0: undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_new'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/ziptool] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/ziptool.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is openssl version?

Comment: @snehal Openssl version is 1.0.2k

Comment: Update openssl version to 1.1.1 or above.

Comment: @snehal I think embedded in CWP. How can I update openssl manually?

Comment: can you provide ./configure --with-zip output?